# Sending Keystrokes to a X Window

Tags: c++, ubuntu, x11, xdotool

I am currently experimenting with xdotool to send keys to a process (I understand that it may not work for all processes that does not set _NET_WM_PID). I have trouble sending keystrokes to windows other from the focus. It does work if you are sending keystrokes to the `CURRENTWINDOW`. Below is the snippet that I used to test xdotool's functionality.

```
extern "C"{
  #include <xdo.h>
}
//extern "C" xdo_window_search
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    xdo_t* p_xdo = xdo_new(NULL);

    // Allocate memory for search query.
    xdo_search_t s;
    // Clear the allocated memory.
    memset(&s, 0, sizeof(xdo_search_t));
    // Set the search query.
    s.pid = 1916;
    s.max_depth = -1;
    s.searchmask = SEARCH_PID;
    s.require = xdo_search::SEARCH_ANY;
    // Allocate memory for output
    Window* windows;
    int no_windows;
    xdo_window_search(p_xdo,&s,&windows,&no_windows);
    cout << no_windows << endl;
    // Prints all windows' names with matching criteria
    for( int i=0;i<no_windows;i++ ){
        unsigned char * name;
        int size;
        int type;
        xdo_get_window_name(p_xdo,windows[i],&name,&size,&type);
        cout << i << ":" << name << endl;
    }
    for( int i=0;i<no_windows;i++ ){
        xdo_type(p_xdo,windows[i],"Hello World",0);
    }
    //xdo_type(p_xdo,CURRENTWINDOW,"Hello World",0); // This does work.
    return 0;
}
```

In additional to testing xdotool's functionality, I've looked into xdotool's source code. Interestingly, I found that they are using Xtest to send keystrokes to the focused window (`CURRENTWINDOW`) and X11's `XSendEvent` for other windows. I turned to xdotool because I couldn't get XSendEvent to work and Xtest cannot send keys to any other windows than the focused window.

Am I not using the xdotool correctly? Does xdotool not work with all *nix OS with X11?

[I am running this on Ubuntu 13.04.]

---

**EDIT**

So, it looks like that does work but not for all windows that it finds. For example, it works for firefox but not gedit and gnome-terminal although it found gedit and gnome-terminal by its pid. It behaves differently if I used `CURRENTWINDOW`.

So, it would be great if someone can explain why is this so. Like, is it related the force send flag in an XEvent?

Comment: Just a comment: I found sikuli to be quite useful when trying to send arbitrary mouse and keyboard events to windows. If you're not tied to xdotool you might want to give sikuli a try.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I am not tied to xdotool. I have already implemented a solution through Xlib and Xtest. I will look into it if I need to send arbitrary mouse events. Thank you.

Comment: @swtdrgn Could you share your Xlib and Xtest alternative solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Directly from the xdotool manual:

> **SENDEVENT NOTES**
>
> If you are trying to send key input to a specific window, and it does
>          not appear to be working, then it's likely your application is ignoring
>          the events xdotool is generating. This is fairly common.
>
> Sending keystrokes to a specific window uses a different API than
>          simply typing to the active window. If you specify 'xdotool type
>          --window 12345 hello' xdotool will generate key events and send them
>          directly to window 12345.  **However, X11 servers will set a special flag
>          on all events generated in this way (see XEvent.xany.send_event in
>          X11's manual). Many programs observe this flag and reject these events.**
>
> It is important to note that for key and mouse events, we only use
>          XSendEvent when a specific window is targeted. Otherwise, we use XTEST.
>
> Some programs can be configured to accept events even if they are
>          generated by xdotool. Seek the documentation of your application for
>          help.
>
> Specific application notes (from the author's testing): * Firefox 3
>          seems to ignore all input when it does not have focus.  * xterm can be
>          configured while running with ctrl+leftclick, 'Allow SendEvents' *
>          gnome-terminal appears to accept generated input by default.

Comment: Can't xdotool just provide a way to *not* set the flag?  There are immeasurably more applications that have no way to override this "ignoring" behavior than applications that do, so this would seem to make more sense.

Comment: It has been a long time since I looked at this. It probably has to do with the underlying libraries that xdotool uses. Both of which sets the flag.