# How to get the window id of a window using c++ program in ubuntu?

Tags: c++, ubuntu

I am using ubuntu. The command to get window id of a window by its name in terminal is

xdotool search --name "name of the window"

But i want to get the same using c++ program.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool/blob/master/cmd_search.c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

References:

[Sending Keystrokes to a X Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16714928/sending-keystrokes-to-a-x-window)

[Github](http://www.github.com/jordansissel/xdotool/blob/master/cmd_search.c)

I cannot compile myself and check, but I think this is the minimal code to search for a window by name.

```
#include <xdo.h>

Window *list;
xdo_search_t search;
unsigned int nwindows;
memset(&search, 0, sizeof(xdo_search_t));
search.max_depth = -1;
search.require = xdo_search::SEARCH_ANY;

search.searchmask |= SEARCH_NAME;
search.winname = "enter name here";

// the context
xdo_t* p_xdo = xdo_new(NULL);
int id = xdo_window_search(p_xdo, &search, &list, &nwindows);
```

Comment: I am getting two errors.                                             error: 'SEARCH_ANY' was not declared in this scope               error: 'xdo_search_windows' was not declared in this scope

Comment: sorry again getting two errors.error: undefined reference to `xdo_new' , error: undefined reference to `xdo_window_search'.

Comment: @Bavani  Undefined reference sounds like a linker error. Make sure you're specifying the right library with `-l`.

Comment: I linked the library libxdo.so with program. but still error: undefined reference to `xdo_window_search(xdo const*, xdo_search const*, unsigned long**, int*)' . Do you know the reason?

Comment: Several things to try: Specifiy `-lxdo`, not `-llibxdo.so`. Specify the location of the library with `-L` (example: `-L/xdo-install/lib`). Make sure that `-lxdo` comes at the end of your gcc invocation, like: `g++ -L/xdo-install/lib -o main main.cpp -lxdo`.

Comment: this can be cause by c++ name mangling. Try to put the "#include <xdo.h>" inside a extern "C" {} block.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same proble for `xdo_window_search`. Check the function's name in `xdo.h`, because of changing names.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem with (`xdo_window_search` changed to `xdo_search_windows` as ewen said)

```
undefined reference to xdo_new'
undefined reference to xdo_search_windows'
```

it was fixed using in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install libxdo-dev
```

in addition to, in cpp file,

```
#include <xdotool-master/xdo.h>
```

in my particular case, was used for a qt application. For it, I've had to add the line below in .pro file too

```
LIBS += -lxdo
```

but the last variable 'id' always returns zero (0).

To get the window ID definitively, I used code in link below, using xdotool command too. In this case, the use should be carefully, because a program can generate more than one ID until fully open and the code runs faster than the ID is available to read. So a timer or a another strategy is necessary.

[How do I execute a command and get the output of the command within C++ using POSIX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478898/how-do-i-execute-a-command-and-get-the-output-of-the-command-within-c-using-po)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29982584)